# Entity Framework Code First On Insert method hooks

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to attach an audit log to an entity I've written, I'm wondering if there are hooks into a context that I can override to provide the desired functionality.

What I'm looking to do is:

- On Insert run method A
- On Update run method B
- On Delete run method C

I could manually add this in a controller but I'd rather a more concrete solution, the desired effect is that no method can insert into the table without also inserting into the audit log.

Comment: EF Code first no I don't use .tt templates

Comment: Why not implement in the database using triggers?

Comment: I'm looking for the EF code first version of triggers, I want to stay out the DB layer if possible. (so far, so good!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This project](https://github.com/kmckelvin/EFHooks) shows how you can add pre- and post-action hooks into an Entity Framework 4.1 DbContext. You can either extend its `HooksDbContext` class or see [how it implements the hooks](https://github.com/kmckelvin/EFHooks/blob/master/EFHooks/HookedDbContext.cs) in the code and change it to suit your purposes.

Comment: Thanks, I took a look at the source code, it only applies context wide hooks which aren't exactly what I was looking for. I could do a more specific version of their implementation by overwriting the save changes method in my class.The disadvantage is that I don't like how that'd run this conditional code on all inserts for that context when it's only 1 Dbset<T> I'd like this custom hook to apply too (unless I missed something).