# C# LINQ detect insert

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a `Web API` where i want to trigger a function when a new row has been inserted to a DB table. I don't want to have to get all the data and look for new data manually.

Is it possible to have a `SQL Server trigger` that somehow calls a function in my `C# Web API`?

How can this be done? Is it a good idea?

Comment: You can use a Service Broker to receive messages from the database engine. Have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15225147/watch-for-a-table-new-records-in-sql-database).

Comment: The broader question here, "how to structure my application so that I can react to it putting things in the database" is probably too broad for a Q&A site such as Stack Overflow. The actual question here, "Can I get a SQL Server trigger to talk to my web application, in that direction", then probably not. You could maybe do it by using SQLCLR but no, it is not a good idea. There are plenty of alternatives, such as SqlCacheDependency or just structuring your code to do the inserts using a framework that can tell you this but then we're off into the too-broad country.

Comment: Have you checked the answers?

Answer (score 4):

You can override [**SubmitChanges**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.submitchanges(v=vs.110).aspx) in your [**DataContext**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext(v=vs.110).aspx), something like:

```
public override void SubmitChanges(System.Data.Linq.ConflictMode failureMode)
{

    var set = this.GetChangeSet();//list of pending changes

    //Call your methods here
    foreach (var insert in set.Inserts)
    {
        //Insert Logic 
    }
    foreach (var update in set.Updates)
    {
        //Update Logic 
    }
    foreach (var item in set.Deletes)
    {
        //Delete Logic
    }


    base.SubmitChanges(failureMode);//allow the DataContext to perform it's default work (including your new log changes)

}
```

Comment: Does `GetChangesSet` tell you if it is an INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE ?

Comment: @Fourat yes you can detect it, I will update my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you need a `Trigger`? Why not choose a pub/sub system (such as `rabbitmq`, `zeromq`, `redis`...) where you can create a channel and every client pubblish and subscribe to it?
But if you prefer use a trigger here you can find two document on how to consume a sql server ([link1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spike/2010/11/25/how-to-consume-a-web-service-from-within-sql-server-using-sql-clr/) and [link2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/938d9dz2.aspx))